# Looping a program to cover all possible cases c++

Tags: c++, sorting, loops, vector

My program reads in 4 terminal arguments:

1. a text file
2. "bubble", "quick", or "brick" corresponding to the sort the user wants
3. a number between 2 and 392 corresponding to the amount of items from the text file to sort through, and
4. "verbose" or "terse" where  verbose prints the vector once it is sorted and where terse prints the amount of swaps used to sort the data.

For example:

```
./SortAutoData auto-mpg.data.txt bubble 100 terse
```

would print out the amount of sorts needed to do a bubblesort on the first 100 items from auto-mpg.data.txt.

What I need to do is find the number of swaps for each of the three sorts for each amount of elements 2 through 392. Is there a way to increment the amount of data without completely altering my code?

I tried doing this: `for i in {2..392}; do echo ./SortAutoData auto-mpg.data.txt bubble ${i} terse; done` but it doesnt print exactly how I would like. Ideally, i would like for it to print:

```
(sorts for 2 data items)
(sorts for 3 data items)
(sorts for 4 data items)
(sorts for 5 data items)
(sorts for 6 data items)
etc....
```

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide!

Comment: Let me consult my crystal ball

Comment: How does it print, then? And how is that different from what you expected?

Comment: I do understand the question. You were expecting the program to print 
Sort for `n` data items"? Is that just the number of elements the user entered for sort? How is the program behaving currently?